# Solve the trig inequality $\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}<\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)}$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

This can be simplified as
\[
\cos x<-\sin{\frac{x}{2}}
\].

Which I think is impossible to solve because the two functions are not the same.
I have also tried to convert both functions to sines or cosines, but none of my attempts seem to work.

Comment: use double formula for the $\cos x$ so you get a quadratic equation for the sin.

Comment: Why not plot the two function to see the result, then prove it.

Comment: For $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ we would get $0\lt -\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}$ which is not true.

Comment: @Piquito The question is not to prove it $\forall x,$ but to *solve* for $x.$

Answer (score 3):

Here $$\cos x + \sin \frac{x}{2}=(1-2\sin^ 2\frac{x}{2})+\sin \frac{x}{2}$$
taking $\sin \frac{x}{2}=z$
$$1-2z^2+z\lt 0$$
$$\implies(2z+1)(z-1)\gt 0$$
Then either $(2z+1)\gt 0$ and $ (z-1)\gt 0$ or $(2z+1)\lt 0$ and $ (z-1)\lt 0$
i.either $z\gt-\frac{1}{2}$ and $z\gt 1$ (which is impossible because $|z|\le 1$)

Or $z\lt-\frac{1}{2}$ and $z\lt 1$ that is $-1\le z \lt-\frac{1}{2}$
$$\implies-1\le \sin \frac{x}{2}\lt-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies 4nπ + \frac{7π}{3}\lt x\lt 4nπ +\frac{11π}{3}$$ and  where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$